# Prevent pop up if value > 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have a print button with the following code:-

```
  Private Sub CommandButtonPrint_Click()
    MsgBox "Have you Completed the Email Address Field?", vbInformation
    response = MsgBox("Do you really want to print?", vbOKCancel)
    If response = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
    Sheets("New").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
    Range("newused").Select
   End Sub
```

This works fine but what do I need to add to prevent the first message box "Have you Completed the Email Address Field?" popping up if the email address field has already been completed. If it has already been completed I would only want the second message box "Do you really want to print>" popping up

Comment: Where is email captured? In a cell on the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for something like this all you need to do is check if the cell is empty. Let me know if this works

```
Private Sub CommandButtonPrint_Click()
    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A10") 'Change to cell to email cell
    if IsEmpty(rRng.Value) then
        MsgBox "Have you Completed the Email Address Field?", vbInformation
    End If 
    response = MsgBox("Do you really want to print?", vbOKCancel)
    If response = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
    Sheets("New").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
    Range("newused").Select

 End Sub
```

Comment: Yes thanks that works fine, however I would like the pop up to give the option to carry on printing even if the email field is empty rather than automatically closing down

Comment: John Davies  I changed my answer to fit your comment. Don't forget to click the green check mark to mark this question as answered